# How can I fill a curve in ParametricPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, filling

I'd like to fill a curve in a `ParametricPlot3D` in the same way as I might with  `ListPointPlot3D`; i.e.,

```
ListPointPlot3D[data, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Filling -> Bottom]
```

I obtained the data numerically, point-by-point, with MATLAB. I have found a parametric expression for $y$ ($y = f(x)$) and I have a function $F(x, y, z)$, but I want to plot $F$ only for the curve $y = f(x)$, i.e., the 3D surface is defined as

```
Plot3D[x^2 Sin[x] + y^2 Cos[y] - x y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

and I want to plot only the specific line of surface which satisfy $y = f(x) = x^2$ using

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x, x^2, x^2 Sin[x] + y^2 Cos[y] - x y /. y -> x^2}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

I'd like to add a filling, but I don't know how. When I type `Filling ->`, the  *Mathematica* code editor complains (the text becomes red).

Answer (score 9):

Why don't you just use `ListPointPlot3D`

```
ListPointPlot3D[
 Table[{x, x^2, x^2 Sin[x] + y^2 Cos[y] - x y /. y -> x^2}, {x, 0, 1, 
   0.001}], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Filling -> Bottom]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can use the two-parameter version of `ParametricPlot3D`:

```
  ParametricPlot3D[{x, x^2, v ( x^2 Sin[x] + (x^4) Cos[x^2] - x^3)}, {x, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1},
   Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.9], ColorFunction -> (Hue[#2] &)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using `Show` is definitely one option to achieve what you want.

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{x, x^2,x^2 Sin[x] + y^2 Cos[y] - x y /. y -> x^2}, {x, 0, 1}, 
       Mesh -> False, 
       ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow",
       PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Opacity[.8]]], 
     ListPointPlot3D[Table[{x, x^2, x^2 Sin[x] + y^2 Cos[y] - x y /. y -> x^2},
       {x, 0, 1, .002}], 
       PlotStyle -> PointSize[Tiny], 
       ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
       Filling -> Bottom],
       Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

BR

Answer (score 3):

You could fake a parametric plot if you want to keep the `Filling` functionality by using a `RegionFunction` that constrains `y` to "something close" to `x^2`:

```
Plot3D[x^2 Sin[x] + y^2 Cos[y] - x y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 < y < x^2 + .01], 
 PlotPoints -> 80,  
 Filling -> Axis, 
 FillingStyle -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

you may want to tweak the threshold `0.01` in the `RegionFunction`, to scale with the `PlotPoints`. The way it is now defined, it will look poor for less `PlotPoints`. This is quite an inelegant solution compared to the suggestion to plot filling and curve separately.

Comment: I used $x-0.005 < y < x+0.005$ for a similar display.