# Region bounded by the curve

Tags: plotting, graphics, inequalities, filling

How to colour the region "under" the curve? Given that $0<x<3$, $-4<y<4$, $0<z<4$

```
ParametricPlot3D[{3/2, y, Abs[y]/(3/2)^(1/4)}, {y, -4, 4}]
```

[image]

Comment: see [How can I fill a curve in ParametricPlot3D?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22300/how-can-i-fill-a-curve-in-parametricplot3d)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ListPointPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPointPlot3D.html)

```
ListPointPlot3D[
 Table[{3/2, y, Abs[y]/(3/2)^(1/4)}, {y, -4, 4, 0.001}], 
 ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", Filling -> Bottom]
```

[image]